# Branch of Math studying how many points must be added for a path to form.

Tags: probability, graph-theory, connectedness

Start with a board containing all white squares. On each step randomly pick a white square and paint it black. How many steps does it take to form a path of black cells going from right to left side of a board? Black cells form "a path" if a piece moving by one cell up, down, left, or right can get from left to right side of the board by only stepping on black pieces.

Similar problem and one of the first one to be studied:
Take a 137x137 grid of wires and randomly cut nodes until the grid stops conducting electricity. How many nodes has to be broken. (On average about half of the nodes must be broken).

Which branch of math studies such transitions?

Comment: I think current tags answer your question.

Comment: More generally, you may like combinatorics

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_theory

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you! Please mane it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This subject is called [percolation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_theory). It is closely related to the study of [random graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_graph).